# How to create my own datasets like the default datasets in R?

Tags: r

I am a new R user. I like the function `data()` very much, it stored many datasets as default in it and I can use and test them at any time when I want.

Can I also put my own data sets in R like the default datasets, so that I don't have to import them every time when I need them?

Comment: Hi @ping, you are right. I am not asking how to use data() and read.csv(), I know, how to use them. I just want to make my own dataset like the default dataset, so that I don't need to import them every time. I wish I can call my data set just with ´data(my_own_dataset)´ without considering my current workpath and the dataset file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following workflow:

1. Put your data (e.g. a mydataset.CSV) in a `data` folder of your project.
2. Put an R file that does the loading named mydataset.R in the same folder.
3. When you want to use the `data` function, first set the working directory
   to the project folder using `setwd`, then call `data(mydataset, package=character(0))`

Here is an example how the R script can look like:

```
# this code goes into mydataset.R
mydataset <- local({
   dat <- read.csv("mydataset.Csv")
   # some transformations here if necessary
   return(dat)
})
```

If you want to be working directory agnostic, you should consider to put your data in your own package. May the `devtools` package is an option for this.